# Do I need to refresh my Ubuntu laptop by pressing F5 as I do on Windows?

Tags: 20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. My curious mind wants to know if I need to refresh my Ubuntu PC as I do on Windows after turning my PC on. By "refresh" I mean if I need to do something similar to pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or right-clicking and then clicking the *Refresh* button on Windows.

If yes, how do I do that? And if not, why?

Comment: I found [this article](https://fossbytes.com/refresh-option-windows-actually-not-think/) about that. Since I'm clueless about Windows I don't feel like writing an answer, but hopefully someone else can illuminate.

Comment: By default, F5 in many applications is the "refresh" button. This goes for both file explorer, internet browser etc. If you want to reload a web page, then yes you should press F5. However, pressing F5 in Windows doesn't do anything in general. But it may reload the file list in an explorer window etc. You should probably be more specific about why and which application you need to refresh.

Comment: If Gnome has issues, you can press Alt+F2 and Type `r` , then press enter. That refreshes the desktop. But that is rarely needed (mostly due to some broken extensions).

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I wanted to know refreshing just after starting my PC, not in any specific application.

Answer (score 0):

I am disregarding the refresh in applications (like a browser to refresh a web page).

For the desktop the answer is: no.

For the desktop there you can press F5 on the desktop and it refreshes the icons on the desktop. It will reload the cached icons. You can do that after  you change the directory where the desktop lives (you can change it in `~/config/users-dirs.dirs`) or if you start messing with the cached icons (generally neither are done by a desktop user and if it is not likely to be more than once). This reloading is also done automatically after a little bit of time (when the system detects a change to the desktop for instance by adding a new item).

Mind that this should also not be needed on Windows and that this should be a bug.